# How to fix "Not syncing ingress default/test-app as it does not contain necessary annotations"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, cert-manager

I followed this great guide on enabling auto TLS creation on kubernetes:
https://akomljen.com/get-automatic-https-with-lets-encrypt-and-kubernetes-ingress/

You set up cert-manager against a custom resource ClusterIssuer with letsencrypt and use the annotation kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true" in your deployment project.

However cert-manager never get's the certificate.

```
1 controller.go:168] ingress-shim controller: syncing item 'default/test-app-ghost'
1 sync.go:65] Not syncing ingress default/test-app-ghost as it does not contain necessary annotations
1 controller.go:182] ingress-shim controller: Finished processing work item "default/test-app-ghost"
```

I'm reading through the documentations and other tutorials and I can't seem to figure out what annotations I'm missing or what settings might be wrong. I redid all the steps several times as well and could not get it to work.

Comment: judging by the rest of the links this is kops in AWS?

Comment: It's actually EKS in AWS! I found the error though. Those values for the test-app don't transcribe correctly in the ghost chart. Making your own Ingress yaml solves the problem.